# How send confirmation email when user perform register method twice?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

In register class I wrote method that raise_exception is true and check email must be unique because I used jwt authentication with email.
When user perform this method for one time ,he get email confirmation .if user don't confirm and run register method for second time .he occure error email is registered. Because this email for one time has been registered in data base.
How can I handle this issue?

Comment: So you want the user to be able to register the email to the database a second time using the same email? I don't think that's possible because as your suggested the email must be unique. What you could do is handle the flow so when the email isn't unique you can patch and resend the email or whatever you needed to do.

Comment: @Cl0ud-l3ss because i need email unique, i do not want users to have same email in db